# How to make a sideways bone?

Tags: modeling, game-engine, rigging

This may seem sort of confusing after you read the title, but it is fairly simple. First, look at the following handgun below (glock):
[image]
Imagine I recreated this in blender, and I started rigging. Look at the magazine, it does not fall straight down. *It falls at an angle.* How would I make a bone that controls a piece of the model (I know how to do this part), but can move it at an angle? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Some sort of constraint probably

Comment: You can create a bone in an angle that will be scalable, add a child bone that will not inherit the scale, and parent the magazine to the child bone.

Comment: A [custom transform orientation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Orientations#Custom_Orientations) perhaps? This lets you move, rotate or scale an object (bone, mesh, lamp, camera, whatever) along another object's local axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bones in blender are not limited to one axis, thus moving them along an angle is easy.

You can constrain it to 2 axes (say X and Z by pressing SHIFT+Y after pressing G) when moving, and this is likely what you want. Insert a keyframe at the bone's resting position, then advance a few frames, and move the bone along the 2 axes so that it lines up with the grip. You can even start to rotate it after its exiting the grip. There is no need for it to follow the grip exactly, because this wont even happen in real life. Just move it approximately and you should get great results.

Comment: Yeah i've figured this out right before you posted; I have my reload animation finished. Thanks though, this will also help new users.